# (explore-exploit + supervised learning ) vs contextual bandits

Tags: supervised-learning, contextual-bandits, exploration-strategies

Lets take an ad recommendation problem for 1 slot. Feedback is click/no click. I can solve this by contextual bandits. But I can also introduce exploration in supervised learning, I learn my model from collected data every k hours.

What can contextual bandits give me in this example which supervised learning + exploration cannot do?

Comment: Hello. Can you please clarify what you mean by "I can also introduce exploration in supervised learning"? What's your idea more specifically?

Comment: I will learn a supervised model from the logging policy/model 's data and I will use it in a stochastic way which will promote exploration. If I do this iteratively(i.e. learn model with IPW supervised loss and collect data with exploration), i hope i can achieve what a batch learning with bandit feedback setup will also achieve. I will use inverse propensity weights in bandits and supervised learning loss as well. 

then my question is that for this specific problem is, will bandit give me anything i cannot achieve with a IPW supervised loss.

Comment: the whole point is working in a practical setup and trying to learn from partial observations i.e. in recommendation you dont have data for what you dont recommend. 

learned stuff from this ( http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs7792/2018fa/ ) . batch learning with bandit feedback seems exciting to me. But how do i convince myself that for simple problem as explained in the question exploration plus inverse propensity weighted supervised loss is equal to a batch learned bandit. IPW supervised loss will obviously require less iterations over data.

Comment: In the example in question description, i can have a softmax over candidates for that slot. exploration will let me try different candidates and hence collecting data by exploration.

Comment: I'm wondering the same question. Bandit is not "an algorithm", it is a modeling setup. Your bandit will follow a policy π. 
You say your policy π is based on a supervised model (disregard exploration for now). I believe that your supervision signal (click) would directly translate to a reward that you get at time t. In non-bandit agents, RL would optimize for long term future rewards. Bandit is a one-episode game, so I think supervised learning is equivalent to RL.  The benefits you get by posing problem as bandit is you can reason about and control your exploration

Comment: No. If I am using IPW weighted supervised loss then actually cross-entropy is my negative reward and click is consumed in the loss.